# How would one install a wall-mounted toilet when the original is on a concrete slab?

Tags: toilet

1973 framed townhome.  I can do whatever I want to the slab, which is 4" thick.  The current drain for the toilet is standard, but it travels through a 4" slab.

The wall behind the toilet(s) are 1/2" drywall with 2x3 studs @ 16" on center and the space between the drywall on either side of the wall is about 12" (room for dryer vent).

So, I have enough depth for a wall-mounted toilet.

What I don't have is a wide enough stud, so I imagine I would need to re-frame a section of the wall to widen it.

2nd, and more costly is going to be moving the drain for the toilet.

Since it runs through a slab, I foresee that I would need to bust through the slab far enough to be able to re-fit the drain such that it's centered on the wall plate below the new toilet tank.

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Any chance you have enough room to fur out the wall (i.e. build a false wall) so that it sits on top of your existing drain? A foot of wall room wasted = no moving the in-slab drain and still lets you keep magazines under the toilet. You could even build a nifty hidden shelving unit into the wall above the toilet for storage.

Comment: Negatory.  I thought of that, but it would look terrible.  If it was a water closet I could get away with it as long as the door didn't hit the front of the toilet, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Reframing behind and busting open the slab seems typical for going from a standard toilet to a wall-mounted.  My question is - why?

Comment: You make a good argument @DMoore.  Design.  Ease of cleaning.  Aesthetics.  Luxury.  That's all.

Comment: @JonGriffith - a lot of gas stations near me have wall mounted toilets... Not sure I feel luxurious... I install a lot of these in France as they are common.   However over there it is common to have a nook/shelf extension that the tank is installed in - it makes repairing easier (not nearly as easy as regular toilets).   Just FYI as I have flipped and built my share of homes, most people will not think of a wall mounted toilet as a plus.   They won't know what to do with it - repair wise.   Also most won't think it looks a lot better either.   If you want it install it but its more work.

Comment: Valid points.  They are not very common around here.  The allure for me is trying to get everything off of the floor throughout the house.  I'll probably ditch the idea for practicality sake.

Comment: If you were starting fresh I would say go either way.   But I would also suggest building the faux shelf to store the tank.   You do not want a tank inside a wall.   (first it would have to be 2x6 minimum and second couldn't be outside wall)